# Constructors and inheritance in Groovy

Tags: constructor, groovy

I am new to Groovy and I am having a little problem with constructors of subclasses. Basically, I have a base abstract class like

```
class BaseClass {
  def BaseClass(Map options) {
    // Does something with options,
    // mainly initialization.
  }
  // More methods
}
```

and a bunch of derived classes like

```
class AnotherClass extends BaseClass {
  // Does stuff
}
```

I would like to be able to create instances like

```
def someObject = new AnotherClass(foo: 1, bar: 2)
```

Unfortunately, Groovy creates automatically all sorts of constructors for `AnotherClass`, with various signatures - based on the properties of `AnotherClass` - but will not allow me to just reuse the constructor in `BaseClass`. I have to manually create one like

```
class AnotherClass extends BaseClass {
  def AnotherClass(options) {
    super(options)
  }
  // Does stuff
}
```

It feels repetitive doing so for each subclass, and it is probably the wrong way.

What would be the Groovy way to share some logic in the constructor?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`@InheritConstructors` is probably what you are looking for:

```
@InheritConstructors
class AnotherClass extends BaseClass {}
```

will create the constructors corresponding to the superclass constructors for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for! By the way, for possible future readers, `InheritConstructors` lives in the package `groovy.transform`.